# clojure: reagent: how to create reaction atom

Tags: clojure, reagent

### Github/Google

I know that the answer is out there on Google/Github. (I know this is possible because I read documentation for it at some past point.) However, I can't seem to find it at all.

### General Background

Clojure Reagent has an "r/atom" of the form

```
  (def some-input (r/atom ""))
```

Then, if I define a component, like:

```
(fn []
  [:div @some-input])
```

It has the property that when the some-input atom changes, the div updates.

### Reaction Atom

Clojure Reagent has something called "reaction", where we can define:

```
(def ra (r/atom ""))
(def rb ... I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE ...)
```

with the property that @rb = (f @ra) -- in such a way so that whenever ra is updated, rb automatically updates to (f @ra)

I believe this is called "reaction atom" or something -- but I can't find it.

### Actual question:

What do I put in the:

```
(def rb ... I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE ...)
```

### Edit Resolved:

It's documented https://github.com/Day8/re-frame
(another very cool project, which also uses Reagent)

The concrete example is:

```
(def app-db  (reagent/atom {:a 1}))           ;; our root ratom  (signal)

(def ratom2  (reaction {:b (:a @app-db)}))    ;; reaction wraps a computation, returns a signal
(def ratom3  (reaction (condp = (:b @ratom2)  ;; reaction wraps another computation
                         0 "World"
                         1 "Hello")))
```

Comment: i don't know anything about reagent, but i think here is the relavant doc from [github](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent#examples): `Any component that dereferences a reagent.core/atom will be automatically re-rendered.` - so it happens automagically ?
EDIT: or maybe [track](http://blog.ducky.io/reagent-docs/0.6.0-alpha2/reagent.core.html#var-track)?

Comment: @birdspider: good try! It's actually "reaction" https://github.com/Day8/re-frame (problem is: it appears to not be on the reagent github, but on the documentation of *a library that uses reagent*)

Comment: ah its a macro @ in [ratom](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/src/reagent/ratom.clj#L5) ns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicating answer from Question just to mark question as resolved:

```
(def app-db  (reagent/atom {:a 1}))           ;; our root ratom  (signal)

(def ratom2  (reaction {:b (:a @app-db)}))    ;; reaction wraps a computation, returns a signal
(def ratom3  (reaction (condp = (:b @ratom2)  ;; reaction wraps another computation
                     0 "World"
                     1 "Hello")))
```

Comment: I would have guessed it's http://blog.ducky.io/reagent-docs/0.6.0-alpha2/reagent.core.html#var-cursor that you want, no?